# Keep context of matplotlib plots in docstrings

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-sphinx

I know that I'm able to keep the context of pieces of code in a **.rst** file with the option `:context: close-figs`.

I'm trying to do the same in a **.py** file, plotting with matplotlib for each method in a module documentation. But I'm getting a error as if the variable defined in the first piece of code (from the first method) is not in the same context of the second plot.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Include a context in the docstring of a method:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def blah(x, y): 
    """ 
    Do whatever and then plot it.

    .. plot::
        :context: close-figs
        
        import your_lib as yl

        a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        b = [-1, -2, 0, 2, 1]
        bleh = ly.blah(a, b)
    """
    return x, y

def plot_coordinates(x, y): 
    """ 
    Plots a series of coordinates.

    .. plot::
        :context: close-figs

        yl.plot_coordinates(a, b)
    """
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)

    return plt.show()
```

2. Run Sphinx in your docs folder: `make html`
3. The result is a NameError, as if the variables "a" and "b" were not defined in the prior block of code.

```
(...)/matplotlib/sphinxext/plot_directive.py", line 484, in run_code
    exec(code, ns)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Reference: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/devel/plot_directive.html

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] .

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: What is `your_lib`? It is imported using `import your_lib as yl` but later you use `ly` .

Comment: It's just an example name. The idea is that you're importing the same library you're working on and plotting examples of it in the docs. The mispelling was my fault.

Comment: I understand that it is "an example name". I asked for a proper [mcve], but you did not provide one. In any case, my guess is that the context is only kept within one RST file, or one docstring.